# unit testing function elisp

Tags: unit-testing, testing, elisp

I am trying to create my own unit test function.

```
;;function
(defun multiply-2 (number)
   (* 2 number))


;;test function
(defun test (function parameters result)
(with-output-to-temp-buffer "tests"
     (progn
     (if (equal (#'function parameters) result) (print "teste ok") (print "fail"))
     )))

;;using test function
(test multiply-2 2 4)
```

But when i run this code i am getting this error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable multiply-2)
  (test multiply-2 2 4)
  eval((test multiply-2 2 4) nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you're not quoting `multiply-2` when you pass it to the `test` function. Change your invocation to

```
(test #'multiply-2 2 4)
```

Next, use `funcall` to properly invoke the function to be tested:

```
(if (equal (funcall function parameters) result)
    (print "test ok")
  (print "fail"))
```

Answer (score 0):

[buttercup](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/emacs-buttercup) is test-driven framework for elisp. I think it's a better choice.